# Paths between 0-cells in a classifying space. II

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category and $X,Y$ objects within.

> If $X$ and $Y$ (as $0$-cells)  lie within the same path-component in $B\mathcal{C}$, can one say anything in general on how $X$ and $Y$ are related in $\mathcal{C}$?

This is a follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333180/paths-between-0-cells-in-a-classifying-space) question. I had thought that maybe there might exist a morphism from one of the objects to the other, but this is false. Is it maybe true that there exists a sequence of objects $X = Z_0, Z_1, \dots, Z_n = Y$ such that there exists an arrow $Z_i \to Z_{i+1}$ or $Z_i \leftarrow Z_{i+1}$ for each $i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe in the last paragraph is the equivalence relation of being connected on the class of objects of a category. Every category is the disjoint union of its connected components, and the classifying space preserves disjoint unions, as can be checked directly. The answer to your question is therefore: Yes.

This argument also shows (as confirmed by the nlab article on [connected categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+category)) that a category is connected if and only if its classifying space is connected.

Comment: Doesn't your answer beg the question? How do we know that the objects comprising the 0-cells in a given path-component all belong to the same component in the category?

Comment: If $X,Y$ are not connected in $C$, then $C = C' \sqcup C''$ as categories with $X \in C'$ and $Y \in C''$. Then $B(C) = B(C') \sqcup B(C'')$, so that there is no path between cells in $B(C')$ and cells in $B(C'')$.

Comment: Great, Got it. Thanks, Martin.